# Simple "Hello-World", null-free shellcode for Windows needed

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, shellcode

I would like to test a buffer-overflow by writing "Hello World" to console (using Windows XP 32-Bit). The shellcode needs to be null-free in order to be passed by "scanf" into the program I want to overflow. I've found plenty of assembly-tutorials for Linux, however none for Windows. Could someone please step me through this using NASM? Thxxx!

Comment: Well, assembly opcodes are the same for both linux and windows, things on those tutorial should apply on windows too.

Comment: Assembly opcodes are the same, but syscalls are different. See my answer below for more details. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assembly opcodes are the same, so the regular tricks to produce null-free shellcodes still apply, but the way to make system calls is different.

In Linux you make system calls with the "int 0x80" instruction, while on Windows you must use DLL libraries and do normal usermode calls to their exported functions.

For that reason, on Windows your shellcode must either:

- Hardcode the Win32 API function addresses (most likely will only work on your machine)
- Use a Win32 API resolver shellcode (works on every Windows version)

If you're just learning, for now it's probably easier to just hardcode the addresses you see in the debugger. To make the calls position independent you can load the addresses in registers. For example, a call to a function with 4 arguments:

```
PUSH 4                  ; argument #4 to the function
PUSH 3                  ; argument #3 to the function
PUSH 2                  ; argument #2 to the function
PUSH 1                  ; argument #1 to the function
MOV EAX, 0xDEADBEEF     ; put the address of the function to call
CALL EAX
```

Note that the argument are pushed in reverse order. After the CALL instruction EAX contains the return value, and the stack will be just like it was before (i.e. the function pops its own arguments). The ECX and EDX registers may contain garbage, so don't rely on them keeping their values after the call.

A direct CALL instruction won't work, because those are position dependent.

To avoid zeros in the address itself try any of the null-free tricks for x86 shellcode, there are many out there but my favorite (albeit lengthy) is encoding the values using XOR instructions:

```
MOV EAX, 0xDEADBEEF ^ 0xFFFFFFFF   ; your value xor'ed against an arbitrary mask
XOR EAX, 0xFFFFFFFF                ; the arbitrary mask
```

You can also try NEG EAX or NOT EAX (sign inversion and bit flipping) to see if they work, it's much cheaper (two bytes each).

You can get help on the different API functions you can call here: http://msdn.microsoft.com

The most important ones you'll need are probably the following:

- WinExec(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687393(VS.85).aspx
- LoadLibrary(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx
- GetProcAddress(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

The first launches a command, the next two are for loading DLL files and getting the addresses of its functions.

Here's a complete tutorial on writing Windows shellcodes: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325776/The-Art-of-Win32-Shellcoding

Answer (score 0):

Assembly language is defined by your processor, and assembly syntax is defined by the assembler (hence, at&t, and intel syntax) The main difference (at least i think it used to be...) is that windows is real-mode (call the actual interrupts to do stuff, and you can use all the memory accessible to your computer, instead of just your program) and linux is protected mode (You only have access to memory in your program's little cubby of memory, and you have to call int 0x80 and make calls to the kernel, instead of making calls to the hardware and bios) Anyway, hello world type stuff would more-or-less be the same between linux and windows, as long as they are compatible processors.

To get the shellcode from your program you've made, just load it into your target system's
debugger (gdb for linux, and debug for windows) and in debug, type d (or was it u?  Anyway, it should say if you type h (help)) and between instructions and memory will be the opcodes.
Just copy them all over to your text editor into one string, and maybe make a program that translates them all into their ascii values.  Not sure how to do this in gdb tho...

Anyway, to make it into a bof exploit, enter aaaaa... and keep adding a's until it crashes
from a buffer overflow error.  But find exactly how many a's it takes to crash it.  Then, it should tell you what memory adress that was.  Usually it should tell you in the error message.  If it says '9797[rest of original return adress]' then you got it.  Now u gotta use ur debugger to find out where this was.  disassemble the program with your debugger and look for where scanf was called.  Set a breakpoint there, run and examine the stack.  Look for all those 97's (which i forgot to mention is the ascii number for 'a'.) and see where they end.  Then remove breakpoint and type the amount of a's you found out it took (exactly the amount.  If the error message was "buffer overflow at '97[rest of original return adress]" then remove that last a, put the adress you found examining the stack, and insert your shellcode.  If all goes well, you should see your shellcode execute.

Happy hacking...

Comment: There are several problems with this reply. 1) Windows is **not** realmode. 2) Windows and Linux hello world code are quite different, since Windows is not POSIX. 3) It's best to Google the answer instead of trusting your memory. 4) The explanation on how to exploit a bof is rather confusing, incomplete, and really not related to the question.